# Що означає закінчення "-чка" (Сердючка, Бойчучка, Кравчучка)?

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви

Вочевидь ці слова утворені від прізвищ:

- Сердючка - від Сердюк,
- Кравчучка - від Кравчук,
- Бойчучка - від Бойчук.

Питання: чи так називали дружин чоловіків з такими прізвищами, чи доньок (щось інше)?

У словнику є означення "одиначка":

> ОДИНАЧКА, и, жін.
>   1. Жіночий рід до одинак 1, 2. Одиначка без матері, хоч і без земельки, та сама собі господиня! (Іван Ле, В снопі.., 1960, 31);
>   2. розм. Єдина дочка. А Ганна була, як і вона, удова, мала собі дочку-одиначку, звали Химою (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 50); Вона була в них одиначка, тож родичі були певні, що ще лучиться їй якийсь королевич (Лесь Мартович, Тв., 1954, 333).

Одинак 1, 2 це відповідно:

> ОДИНА́К, а ч.
>   1. Той, хто сам, без інших, відокремився від людей; Той, хто уникає інших людей; Той, хто не спирається на допомогу або підтримку інших.
>   2. Той, хто не має сім'ї, рідних.
>   3. розм. Єдиний син. В родині було три доньки і син-одинак «Олесь»

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Це називається [андро́нім](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC), а саме "іменування жінки за іменем, прізвищем чи прізвиськом її чоловіка", й утворюватися він може не лише за допомогою "-чк".

До прикладу, наші дівчата на Сумщині також називали одна одну за прізвищем (оскільки вони були незаміжні, то бралося прізвище батька):

> Улько ⇒ Ульчиха
>   Лимар ⇒ Лимарша
>   Тютюнник ⇒ Тютюнничка

У західних областях поширене іменування жінки за чоловіком, утворене за допомогою суфікса -ов (у варіаціях). Наприклад, *Міковчак* - *Міковчак**ов**а*, *Клука* - *Клук**ов**а*. На кшталт того, як це у польскій, чеській, словацькій тощо мовах, де такі варіанти мають офіційну форму (прізвище в паспорті). Втім, не слід плутати з російськими схожими за звучанням прізвищами, оскільки в російській додається тільки закінчення жіночого роду (*Виноградов* - *Виноградов**а***).

Ще в Україні зустрічається іменування дочок за характером діяльності батька, що утворюється за допомогою суфікса -івн (у варіаціях). Наприклад, *поп**івн**а*, *лимар**івн**а* тощо.

Comment: В чеській мові доходить до кумедного: коли російянка виходить заміж за хлопця на прізвище **Попов** (і шлюб реєструється в Чехії), то в чеських документах вона записується як **Поповова**.