# Фемінітиви: як відмежувати значення „дружина — назва професії“ та „назва роду — діяльності“?

Tags: фемінітиви, рід

Якими мовними засобами можна ефективніше відмежувати, розрізнити для слухач·ів/читач·ів фемінітив, цебто форму жіночого роду, напр. [отаманша](/q/1229/), докторка, міністерка від схожої чи й повнозбіжної форми на позначення „дружина, шлюбна партнерка «назва професії», «назва діяльності», «назва зайнятості» чоловіка“, як-то отаманша = дружина отамана, докторка = дружина доктора тощо?

На думку спадає лише контекстуальне прояснення штибу „міністерка підписала наказ про“, „отаманша повела свою ватагу до бою“ тощо.

Comment: Є дещо схоже запитання, [«Що означає закінчення “-чка” (Сердючка, Бойчучка, Кравчучка)?»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/545/).

Comment: От у поляків усе просто: докторка лікує, докторо́ва — тільки дружина того, хто лікує.

Answer (score 6):

Натрапила на [інтерв'ю з Оленою Малаховою](http://womo.ua/olena-malahova/), "кандидаткою філологічних наук, доценткою, радницею з питань політики гендерної рівності та антидискримінації в освіті міністерки освіти і науки України", у якому "мовознавиця" з-поміж іншого говорить і про запитуване.

> **За якою логікою тим чи іншим іменникам, що називають професію, посаду, сферу діяльності, призначають той чи інший суфікс? Тобто, чому
>   `виступантка`, а не, скажімо, `виступеса`?**
>
> Тут важливо згадати про особливості процесу словотворення. Найбільша
>   кількість фемінітивів утворені від іменників чоловічого роду. От є у
>   світі якась реалія, процес – і спочатку від цієї назви утворився, як
>   правило, іменник чоловічого роду, а вже потім від нього за допомогою
>   «жіночих» суфіксів – відповідний іменник жіночого роду (`учити` –
>   `учит-ель` – `учитель-к-а`). І через частотність саме такого ланцюжка
>   іноді буває важко утворити милозвучні фемінітиви. Там, де
>   словотворення відбулося паралельно – «`дослід-ник`» і «`дослід-ниц-я`»
>   – усе всіх влаштовує.
>
> Загалом **в українській мові є понад 13 суфіксів, які можуть
>   утворювати іменники – назви осіб жіночої статі**. Серед них
>   найпродуктивнішими є суфікси **`-к-`** (*учителька, директорка,
>   лідерка, винищувачка), **`-иц-`** (урядовиця, авантюрниця,
>   очільниця*), ***`-ин-`*** (*філологиня, філософиня, своякиня*),
>   ***`-ес—`*** (*агентеса, адвокатеса, критикеса*), меншою мірою ***`-ис-`*** (*актриса, редактриса*). До речі, деякі суфікси можуть утворювати варіанти фемінітивів з однаковим лексичним значенням:
>   *мовознавиця* і *мовознавчиня*, *чемпіонка* і *чемпіонеса*, *водійка* і *водійчиня*.
>
> Є **суфікси** ***`-ш-`***, ***`-их-`***, які, **утворюючи фемінітиви,
>   вносять до лексичного значення слова додатковий компонент**. Тож
>   «*генеральша*» – це не жінка на генеральській посаді, а дружина
>   генерала, *директорша* – дружина директора. А слова «*повариха*»,
>   «*ткачиха*» (дружина ткача) часто набувають і зневажливого відтінку
>   (порівняйте з нейтральними «*куховарка*», «*ткаля*»). **Тому ці
>   суфікси я б не радила використовувати, якщо ви утворюєте фемінітив.**
>
> **Щодо логіки, за якою обирається суфікс, то передусім спрацьовує не значення слова. Більше впливає корінь – з якої мови він прийшов, на
>   який звук закінчується, чи діють правила щодо чергування приголосних у
>   процесі додавання суфіксів.** **Хоча вже можна говорити й про
>   семантичну тенденцію** – **використання суфікса `-ин-` для творення
>   назв жінок за діяльністю в науковій сфері**: *філологиня, історикиня,
>   фізикиня*. Хоча от «етнографиня» – не дуже сприймають через оте
>   «графиня» на кінці.

Далі "мовознавчиня" радить, **як зробити мову гендерночутливою**.

> Найперше – захотіти цього, це вже половина справи. Інструментально –
>   окрім стратегії фемінізації (творення й уживання фемінітивів) можна
>   застосовувати ще стратегію нейтралізації (уникнення акценту на статі).
>   Замість «*студентки і студенти*» можна сказати / написати, наприклад,
>   «*студентство*», також «*учительство*», «*читацька аудиторія*»,
>   «*медіаспільнота*» – українська мова дає неосяжне поле для творчості.

Також пані Олена Малахова інформує:

> Цього року у Харкові в листопаді відбудеться перший міжнародний
>   лінгвістичний конгрес «Гендер-PRO 2: гендерна лінгвістика і динаміка
>   мовної норми», присвячений саме творенню й уживанню фемінітивів. На
>   нього приїдуть мовознавиці й мовознавці з тих країн, у яких вже
>   відбулися мовні реформи чи відбуваються схожі процеси. Формується
>   група українських лінгвістів/-ок, щоб здійснити дослідження й
>   випрацювати на науковому підґрунті певні рекомендації щодо творення й
>   уживання фемінітивів: який суфікс з яким коренем краще використати, чи
>   відбудеться чергування, чи мають бути якісь стилістичні межі тощо.
>   Мовна норма – це явище динамічне, на відміну від правопису, який
>   певною мірою є статичним, але останній не регулює утворення
>   фемінітивів.

Тож стежте, якщо кого цікавить тема.

Comment: І, звісно, «[фемінітиви](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фемінітиви)» у Вікіпедії. Там зараз є і стаття, і незатведжені зміни до неї, тож цікаво глянути і те, й інше.

Answer (score 5):

#### Ніяк.

Історично так склалося, що терміни для «дружина назва_зайнятості_чоловіка» і «особа жіночої статі, яка займається назва_зайнятості» — еквівалентні або дуже близькі між собою. З часів емансипації жінок ще не з'явилися мовні інструменти для позначення такої різниці.

Наприклад, в українській є слово [*генеральша*](http://sum.in.ua/s/gheneraljsha) — жінка генерала.

Але не варто засмучуватися: в інших мовах — усе те саме. Наприклад, англійське слово [*queen*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=queen) (слово, яке радше позначає вид зайнятості, а не сімейний стан) є коґнатом українського слова [*жона*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhona), тому що вони обидва походять із ПІЄ `*gwen-` (жінка, дружина).
[Ще трошки подробиць](http://www.endic.ru/fasmer/Zhena-4391.html) у словнику Фасмера.

І до речі, саме слово «генерал» (також generate, genetics) походить від Лат. [*genus*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=genus) (вид речей, об'єктів тощо), а воно, у свою чергу — від ПІЄ дієслова `*gen-` (народжувати, виробляти), яке споріднене з `*gwen-`.

Comment: Ви, мені здається, губите те, що не всі такі слова мають розподіл значень «50% ймовірності, що жінка професіонала — 50% ймовірності, що жінка-професіонал». Деякі слова, наприклад та ж [отаманша](http://sum.in.ua/s/otamansha), мають помітку «рідко» біля одного зі значень (хоча конотація може змінюватися з часом), а деякі, наприклад [поетеса](http://sum.in.ua/s/poetesa), — взагалі лише одне значення.

Comment: @Sasha, так. Але у запитанні йшлося про «як відмежувати?», і я це розумію як пошук більш-менш універсального морфологічного правила, яке можна застосовувати до довільного кореня. А такого правила не існує.

Comment: Здається, суфікс *-ес-* більш-менш однозначний (принаймні поетеса — не дружина поета, а стюардеса — не дружина стюарда). Здається, різні суфікси мають різні розподіли ймовірностей.

Comment: @Sasha, цілком можливо. Якщо є така статистика, то це буде чудовою конкуруючою відповіддю.

Comment: Нмд, слів, які позначають дружин, набагато менше використовується в нинішній мові, тож відрізняти можна за часом написання тексту. Та ж міністерка є точно міністром сама по собі.